# DuckDuckGo Not Loading on Firefox

Tags: firefox, duckduckgo

So I came across `{{template.head}}` somewhere and I wanted to search up what it was but right after I tried to search it, I was stuck on a newtab firefox page, unable to access the DuckDuckGo.com website or search anything. So basically I cannot access duckduckgo at all. I tried opening ddg on a private window but it wouldn't load either. I also tried deleting cookies for ddg but it doesn't seem to change anything. Does anyone have an idea of what might be happening and how I could solve the issue?

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9kX2.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a guess.. but probably correct.  Most search engines are a world of ASCII (aka plain ENGLISH text).  Many of these engines BARF when presented with special chars like "{{".  It took YEARS before you could search for "c# classes" and get good results and this was only because of a special case search engines made for the parsers.  It is quite possible that they can't handle the non ASCII text in the query.

Comment: [{{template.head}}](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%7B%7Btemplate.head%7D%7D&ia=web) works for me

Comment: Are you able to navigate to any other site?

Comment: @music2myear This problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a complete idiot now. I just woke up and realized that I had no-script installed and it was blocking ddg because it thought it was trying to run malicious code.